# Deleting records with BLOB is very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, blob, delete-record

We have a Oracle 11g database with several different tables. One of the tables contains around 120,000 records and each record has a BLOB field. The data size in the BLOBs vary from 2-3KB to several MB. The problem is that when we want to delete a record from this table, it takes a long time - sometimes over a minute to delete just one record (using SQL developer or using a DBMS-job). We have no problem with deleting records of the other tables. For test purposes, we set the BLOB field of one record which we wanted to delete to EMPTY_BLOB(), but again deleting this record took a long time.

Is this behaviour normal for records containing BLOB? Is there any way to tune deleting such records so that they can be deleted a bit faster?

Comment: Is it a straight forward delete SQL or triggered from something else.. DELETE is always time consuming irrespective of columns :)

Comment: Something is wrong. I would expect it to take just a few milliseconds. Is the `where` clause in your `delete` statement referencing an indexed field? Do you have any costly triggers on delete?

Comment: @realspirituals: It is a straight forward SQL statement: DELETE TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = XYZ;

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: We delete based on primary key (i.e. ID) of the records. Oracle seems to have a default Index (e.g. SYS_C1234567) on all ID fields. So yes, it is an indexed field. Please note that deleting from other tables based on ID (which are also indexed) does not take so much time. Other tables are relatively bigger with several million records, however, do not have any BLOB fields.

Comment: Can you post your delete statement? Are you reclaiming the space? Is the BLOB column defined as NOLOGGIN?

Comment: Please show the explain plan for `SELECT TABLE_NAME WHERE ID=XYZ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hints, specially the hint related to index. The problem was originated from lack of indexes on foreign keys. Actually, we had a "ON DELETE SET NULL" statement in foreign keys which were not indexed. When we indexed the foreign keys, the delete became very fast.